# Timidity running and hogging one core of my CPU

Tags: debian, systemd, timidity

Twice now (with some time between, a few weeks I think) has Timidity started out of nowhere when I start up my computer from sleep. It takes up all the processing power of one of my cores and has been running now for about 5 to 10 minutes and I would like to know why this process is starting up.

Running `pstree` shows the process as a direct descendant of `systemd` so I guess `systemd` is responsible for starting `timidity`, but I don't know how to look for the configuration that started `timidity`.

If I run `strace` on the process I get the following:

```
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
```

The files that are open by that process are:

```
/dev/null
/dev/snd/timer
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
/dev/snd/controlC0
/dev/snd/seq
```

The command line that ran is:

```
/usr/bin/timidity-Os-iAD
```

These last 3 information are taken from `/proc/$PID/`.

So I ask, how can I find out why `timidity` is being run (I will tackle the problem of why it is taking up all of one cores later).

Comment: Timidity has a daemon, that starts over an init-skript  `Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
`  but I don't know why it consums your core.

Comment: I am not that familiar with `systemd`, can I somehow see where the command is that starts up `timidity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cat /run/systemd/generator.late/timidity.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/timidity
Description=LSB: start and stop timidity
Before=runlevel2.target runlevel3.target runlevel4.target runlevel5.target shutdown.target
After=remote-fs.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=1
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/timidity start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/timidity stop
```

The systemd-unit is generate dynamic by systemd. To prevent the start you can use `chkconfig` or erase the link `/etc/rc2.d/S01timidity` I would prefere `chkconfig --del timidity`