# Why is Timidity taking up all processing power of one core

Tags: debian, timidity

So I asked earlier about [why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331053/timidity-running-and-hogging-one-core-of-my-cpu) `timidity` was running on my system and got a good explanation that related to `systemd`.

Now I am wondering why it is hogging one of my cores (my processor is an AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 640 Processor so it has 4 cores).

If I run strace on the process I get the following (ran it for a few seconds, seems to be repeating so I stopped after that):

```
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(6, SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_GET_QUEUE_STATUS, 0x16c83e0) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x7fff43107780) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HWSYNC, 0x3cd407d5) = 0
```

The files that are open by that process are, according to information in `/proc/$PID/fd`:

```
/dev/null
/dev/snd/timer
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
/dev/snd/controlC0
/dev/snd/seq
```

The Linux distribution is Debian stable (Jessie). Version of `timidity` is `2.13.2-40.2`.

Comment: should also go with debian <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Midi/SoftwareSynthesisHowTo

Comment: That did the trick, following the advice at the end of that article solved my problem. As soon as I had uncommented those lines in the config file then a sound was played (don't know what that was for though) and the CPU usage dropped and timidity is no longer running.

Comment: @Bahamut if you would write that up as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No, it's okay. I gave you only a hint.  You did the trick. :D